# Is python 3.5 an Ubuntu Third Party App?

Tags: discussion

Ref: [how can I create a program with python 3.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241681/how-can-i-create-a-program-with-python-3-5)

This is a question in Ask Ubuntu about creating a program with python3.5.

The Question was closed as being off-topic.

"Help Center > Asking, What topics can I ask about here? Questions that you may ask: Running third-party applications on Ubuntu."

Python is installed in Ubuntu using: `sudo apt-get install python3.5` which would indicate that it is a third party app.

Comment: ***I wanted to create a program with python3.5.:*** This signifies the question was purely a programming question.

Comment: Ignoring the Python part, I would close that question for any number of reasons (needs detail, clarity, focus, not about Ubuntu etc...). It baffles me why you want that reopened when it is so low quality.

Comment: Christopher Turcotte managed to give a new user a good useful answer. That is What Ask Ubuntu is about.

Comment: @Mark Kirby: It baffles me why would you spend time editing the Question "when it is so low quality".

Comment: @C.S.Cameron All I changed was a tag, it was tagged [LTS] and I changed it to [Python]. According to your comment on that post, the post body was edited "The question has been edited "how to find the keywords that could help programming."" but timeline says I am the only editor and I only did a tag. Please tell me what did it used to say?

Answer (score 3):

As the close message says:

> and generic programming questions on Stack Overflow.

That's the epitome of a generic programming question if I ever saw one.